# c++: call a function with with various number of arguments stored in an array?

Tags: c++, assembly, argument-passing

I've got a function with signature `double func(double,...)` and I'm sure all the arguments I'm passing to func are type double. All arguments are stored in some a vector called arguments, I'm just wondering if there is way to write a generic code to pass any number of arguments specified in argumentVector to func?

something like :

```
for (int i=0;i<agumentVector.size();i++)
    pushstack(argumentVector[i]);
res = call(func);
```

so far I've tried this code but it seems to have problems:

```
double* param = &argumentVector[0];

for(int i=0;i<argumentVector.size();i++)
{
    _asm  sub         esp,8;
    _asm  fld         param;
    _asm  fstp        qword ptr [esp];
    param++;

}
_asm  call        func;
_asm  add         esp,10h;
_asm  fstp        qword ptr res;
```

--just a crazy result I'm getting! this code runs without any problems :

```
double x[2] = {5,6};
double *param = x;
double res;

    _asm  sub         esp,8;
    _asm  fld         x;
    _asm  fstp        qword ptr [esp];
    _asm  sub         esp,8;
    _asm  fld         x+8;
    _asm  fstp        qword ptr [esp];
    param++;
_asm  call        p;
_asm  add         esp,10h;
_asm  fstp        qword ptr res;

cout << res << "\n";
```

while in this one arguments are not passed properly!

```
double x[2] = {5,6};
double *param = x;
double res;

    _asm  sub         esp,8;
    _asm  fld         param;
    _asm  fstp        qword ptr [esp];
    _asm  sub         esp,8;
    _asm  fld         param+8;
    _asm  fstp        qword ptr [esp];
    param++;
_asm  call        p;
_asm  add         esp,10h;
_asm  fstp        qword ptr res;

cout << res << "\n";
```

do you have any idea why? I though both x and param were simple arrays!

**--edit2--**

here is the complete assembly code so far VC generates

```
    double x[2] = {5,6};
010E1A05  fld         qword ptr [__real@4014000000000000 (10EB928h)]  
010E1A0B  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-48h]  
010E1A0E  fld         qword ptr [__real@4018000000000000 (10EB878h)]  
010E1A14  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-40h]  
    double *param = x;
010E1A17  lea         eax,[ebp-48h]  
010E1A1A  mov         dword ptr [ebp-54h],eax  
    double res;
    p(param[0],param[1]);
010E1A1D  mov         esi,esp  
010E1A1F  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-54h]  
010E1A22  sub         esp,8  
010E1A25  fld         qword ptr [eax+8]  
010E1A28  fstp        qword ptr [esp]  
010E1A2B  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-54h]  
010E1A2E  sub         esp,8  
010E1A31  fld         qword ptr [ecx]  
010E1A33  fstp        qword ptr [esp]  
010E1A36  call        dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
010E1A39  fstp        st(0)  
010E1A3B  add         esp,10h  
010E1A3E  cmp         esi,esp  
010E1A40  call        @ILT+795(__RTC_CheckEsp) (10E1320h)  

    {
        _asm  sub         esp,8;
010E1A45  sub         esp,8  
        _asm  fld         param+8;
010E1A48  fld         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
        _asm  fstp        qword ptr [esp];
010E1A4B  fstp        qword ptr [esp]  

        _asm  sub         esp,8;
010E1A4E  sub         esp,8  
        _asm  fld         param;
010E1A51  fld         dword ptr [ebp-54h]  
        _asm  fstp        qword ptr [esp];
010E1A54  fstp        qword ptr [esp]  

    }
    _asm  call        p;
010E1A57  call        dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
    _asm  add         esp,10h;
010E1A5A  add         esp,10h  
    _asm  fstp        qword ptr res;
010E1A5D  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-64h]  

    cout << res << "\n";
010E1A60  push        offset string "\n" (10EB834h)  
010E1A65  mov         esi,esp  
010E1A67  sub         esp,8  
010E1A6A  fld         qword ptr [ebp-64h]  
010E1A6D  fstp        qword ptr [esp]  
010E1A70  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (10EF3A8h)]  
010E1A76  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (10EF3ACh)]  
010E1A7C  cmp         esi,esp  
010E1A7E  call        @ILT+795(__RTC_CheckEsp) (10E1320h)  
010E1A83  push        eax  
010E1A84  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (10E1294h)  
010E1A89  add         esp,8  
    return 0;
```

Comment: Can you modify `func()` or are you stuck with having to do everything on the caller's side?

Comment: I can create a test func (as I've already did), but in the end I'm trying to work with some library, so I'm stuck in client side!

Comment: If you have access to variadic templates, it might be possible to do this with recursion and argument preparation in the parameter pack. Just an idea, since I don't have the time right now to write it as a full-fletched answer.

Comment: To be sure, compile it using g++ -S -l so you can show us the rest of the assembly generated at that function call, to see if there is any difference in it.

Comment: @ManuelFerreria I'm using VC but I've posted the assembly code generated by compiler

Comment: Your code shows that there is no difference in `param` or `x`. Are you sure it is different results? You could try to place a breakpoint just before the `call` and review the stack manually, to see if it is indeed different.

Comment: @ManuelFerreria Yeah, and that's exactly why I'm confused! so far in function `p` I'm only printing both inputs, but the inputs (using assembly) are completely uninitialized!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in Visual Studio, but I think you can easily correct the inline assembler syntax so it fits your compiler's requirements.

```
double variadicDoubleFunc(double, ...)
{
}

double callVariadicDoubleFunc(double * doubles, unsigned int numDoubles)
{
    // sizeof(double) must be 8!
    if (numDoubles == 0)
        return 0.0;
    double * lastDouble = doubles + (numDoubles - 1);
    double result = 0.0;

    __asm mov eax, numDoubles
    __asm mov edx, lastDouble
    __asm push esi
    __asm mov esi, esp
    __asm and esp, 0xFFFFFFC0

    __asm label_loop:
    __asm sub esp, 8
    __asm fld qword ptr [edx]
    __asm fstp qword ptr [esp]
    __asm sub edx, 8
    __asm sub eax, 1
    __asm test eax, eax
    __asm jnz label_loop

    __asm call variadicDoubleFunc
    __asm fstp qword ptr result
    __asm mov esp, esi
    __asm pop esi

    return result;
}
```

Comment: so far the best answer but After I copied it into my code it failed to run properly, the first thing that made thing a little messy was `move ebp,esp` and the other one in the end of program, I just changed their position. now only one of two parameters get passed

Comment: I'd like to help you with that, but I can't understand why `move ebp,esp` prevents the code from running properly... Also, what exactly did you do when you "changed their position"? (P.S. There was some small error in the asm code, fixed it now.)

Comment: I've finally made your code work for me! and I've edited your answer to add all my changes! but any way thank for the help. and please tell me if I'm doing something wrong without knowing it! I don't know any assembly, just using VC debugger, I've reached that code!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you now. You replaced `ebp` by a new variable (`temp`), I think you can avoid this by using `esi` instead. I will edit the code in that fashion and include your modifications concerning the return value. If that doesn't work on your compiler please report.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing the values in the correct **reversed** order?

If you have 
`void func(int a, int b, int c)`

you have to do:

```
push c
push b
push a
call func
add esp, 4*3
```

If you just want to embed assembly, and be it executed exactly as you placed it:

```
for(int i=0;i<argumentVector.size();i++)
{
    parm++;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( 
                      "sub         esp,8;"
                      "fld         parm;"
                      "fstp        qword ptr [esp]")

}
__asm__ __volatile__ ( "call        func;"
                       "add         esp,10h;"
                       "fstp        qword ptr res;")
```

But before doing this, be sure that it is indeed an optimization, and not a premature one.

Comment: the problem is the code breaks when I use assembly code inside a for. by the way there is no difference between order of numbers, so far I'm only trying to multiply them all to each other (later I'll correct it)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on my specific requirements, I'd do one of these two you see below. Using Assembly would be last on my list of options.

**Op. 1** If all your arguments are of the same type, why not just pass the vector? It's type safe and you can't overflow like when you use variable length argument lists. Remember that you can also pass beginning and ending iterators if you only want the function to use a part of the vector.

**Op. 2** If your arguments are of different types, use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: none these are my options since I'm trying to use this for some predefined functions. I'm can make sure I'm passing the correct number of arguments, and I know all the parameters are type of double. but I might call this function with various number of arguments!